# Next JS build fails when running 'next build' ~ Can't resolve next.js

Tags: npm, build, module, next.js

When running 'next build' I get the following error and I can't for the life of me figure out what's happening.

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/Users/Rob/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'D:\wlc-landscapes'


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:15:924
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:6:584)
PS D:\wlc-landscapes>
```

I've tried deleting the .next, node_modules, package-lock.json, next global install and then re-installing everything and it still fails. Even when creating a brand new Next JS app and simply trying to build it I get the same error.

When deploying via Netlify it seems to build fine so it looks like this issue is local to my machine. Thanks in advance.